# Android Application Monitoring Airtime

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently started learning programming in the Android Platform and especially in have been building little apps using the Android Telephony Services library. I would like to know if there is any library or a method of Getting an android phones Airtime in Android Studio. I use Android Studio as my IDE. I have been searching for a solution but to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ContentProvider is available, such as: CallLog. Calls. CONTENT_URI, suggest you to learn:[Android ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html)